# Loading executable code through <img> or <a> tags?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss, image

I'm working on an app that would allow people to enter arbitrary URL's that would be included in `<a href="ARBITRARY URL">` and `<img src="ARBITRARY URL" />` tags.

What type of security risks am I looking at?

The app is coded in PHP, and the only security countermeasure I currently perform is using PHP's [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) function against the input URL before sending it as HTML. I'm also checking to make sure that the URL text starts with either `http://` or `https://` but I don't know if that's accomplishing anything, security wise.

What else should I be doing to ensure the security of my end users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [XSS Checklist](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the CodeIgniter framework, which has an xss_clean() function. I tried about half of the examples on that site after passing them through xss_clean() and it replaced all the vulnerable text with the string "[removed]".

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to construct an image that is also a valid javascript file, and get a browser to execute it.  See http://www.thinkfu.com/blog/?p=15

SVG images (mime-type image/svg+xml) can contain javascript.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html

Comment: ... yikes, this is more along the lines of what I was worried about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would like to read about [XSS (Cross site scripting)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [XSRF (Cross site request forgery)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

*EDIT*:
As pointed out by [ryeguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704107/loading-executable-code-through-img-or-a-tags/1704160#1704160), you can pretty much copy and paste any of the examples in [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) and seek the best way to prevent from them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should sanitize at all times, img tags are vulnerable to [cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, it is possible to insert whole images into URLs using [inline data](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/img.html) in newer browsers. It might be possible to inject something through there, however that would require a gaping browser-side security hole and I would not know how to sanitize something like that.

Maybe you just want to restrict access to certain domains, or check whether an image physically exists? That might already help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery):

```
<img src="http://example.org/accounts/123/delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answers so far, the xss cheat sheet doesn't really account for event attributes like onmouseover onhover etc. These are all, by design, to allow someone to run some javascript when something happens.